# How to prevent over-zooming with Croppie (JavaScript image cropping plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, styles

I have a very basic Croppie div being initialized like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="upload-avatar" class="croppie-container"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$uploadCrop = $('#upload-avatar').croppie({
    viewport: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        type: 'square' 
    },
    url: 'test_img.jpg'
});

$('#upload-avatar').croppie('bind');
```

'test_img.jpg' successfully gets loaded into the croppie-container, however Croppie is adding a "scale" style to the image, in hand zooming the image in by 4X.

```
scale(4.1667);
```

'test_img/jpg' is already small enough (212px x 248px) to be moved within the 100px x 100px viewport window to be cropped, so I don't want the image to be zoomed in. Even after copying the code samples on Croppie's site, I still have the same problem. Any idea why Croppie is magnifying my image when I don't want it to? (See image)
[image]

In order for this to work, I would need to upload images 4X the size I want to fit in a 100px x 100px frame, which is ridiculous. Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks!

Croppie docs: http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/#documentation

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. After commenting out the "bind" call, it behaves as I would expect. Strange..

```
$('#upload-avatar').croppie({
    viewport: {
         width: 100,
        height: 100,
        type: 'square' 
    },
    url: json.file
});
//$('#upload-avatar').croppie('bind');   //Commenting this line, fixed it!
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens only first time when you upload image or you bind image . so you can solve this issue by binding same image two times.This is not correct solution but it works for me .

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.5/croppie.min.js" integrity="sha512-Gs+PsXsGkmr+15rqObPJbenQ2wB3qYvTHuJO6YJzPe/dTLvhy0fmae2BcnaozxDo5iaF8emzmCZWbQ1XXiX2Ig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.5/croppie.min.css" integrity="sha512-zxBiDORGDEAYDdKLuYU9X/JaJo/DPzE42UubfBw9yg8Qvb2YRRIQ8v4KsGHOx2H1/+sdSXyXxLXv5r7tHc9ygg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />



    $uploadCrop = $('#upload-profile-pic').croppie({
        enableExif: true,
        viewport: {
            width: 250,
            height: 250,
            type: 'circle'
        },
        boundary: {
            width: 250,
            height: 250
        },
    
    });
    
    
    $('#user_profile').on('change', function() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
                url: e.target.result
            }).then(function() {
    
// show hide crop image related div 
                $('.outerdiv').addClass('d-none');
                $('#upload-profile-pic').removeClass('d-none');
                $('.ufullname').addClass('d-none');
// bind again 
                $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
                    url: e.target.result
                });
    
               
            });
        }
    
    
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    });
```